# Multiple keyframe animations not working in safari

Tags: html, css, animation, safari, css-animations

I'm working with HTML5 banner having a lot of CSS3 animation. To make reusable keyframe animation I'm using multiple animation on single element. It's working perfectly except safari.

**CSS:**

```
.text1 {
    -webkit-animation: fadeOutRight 1s 3s forwards;
    animation: fadeOutRight 1s 3s forwards;
}
.text2 {
    -webkit-animation: fadeInLeft 1s 4s both, fadeOutRight 1s 7s forwards;
    animation: fadeInLeft 1s 4s both, fadeOutRight 1s 7s forwards;
}
.text3 {
    -webkit-animation: fadeInLeft 1s 8s both;
    animation: fadeInLeft 1s 8s both;
}

/* fadeInLeft */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeInLeft {
    0% { -webkit-transform: translateX(-100px); opacity: 0; }
    100% { -webkit-transform: translateX(0px); opacity: 1; }
}
@keyframes fadeInLeft {
    0% { transform: translateX(-100px); opacity: 0; }
    100% { transform: translateX(0px); opacity: 1; }
}

/* fadeOutRight */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeOutRight {
    0% { -webkit-transform: translateX(0px); opacity: 1; }
    100% { -webkit-transform: translateX(100px); opacity: 0; }
}
@keyframes fadeOutRight {
    0% { transform: translateX(0px); opacity: 1; }
    100% { transform: translateX(100px); opacity: 0; }
}
```

[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/animateall/1w1woas0/)

**Workable solutions:**

1. Wrap the element with another/more element & add single animation to each element. This solution needs extra styling for wrapper element.
2. Merge multiple animation into one & this solution increase the complexity of the `keyframes rule` and it's not easily maintainable for complex  animation.
3. According to accepted answer of another [stackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14384494/multiple-css-keyframe-animations-using-transform-property-not-working) –
   `You cannot animate same attribute more than once, on a same element, the last one will overwrite other`.
   It’s only true for safari in my case & first animation is only running not
   second one. If I don’t animate same property on multiple animation
   then it’s also fine for safari([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/animateall/1w1woas0/1/)). This one is not
   suitable for me because I will need to animate same property in
   multiple animations.

**Note:**

Although I'm using multiple animation on same element but I'm not animating at same time, there is delay between each animation.

**Question:**

Is it possible to use multiple CSS3 animation on same element regardless of animating property?

Comment: did you find the solution? I struggled with this problem. I have more than 2 keyframe animations. Apparently, Safari wants animations to be reversed. I tried but after reversed it seems only first 2 of animations works others not.

Answer (score -1):

For some reason, Safari does not read trough the shorthand method for describing the animation, for example:

```
animation: test 1s 2s 3 alternate backwards
```

It needs to be described more detailed with its separate properties listed:

```
.class{
animation-name: bounce;
animation-duration: 4s;
animation-iteration-count: 10;
animation-direction: alternate;
animation-timing-function: ease-out;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
animation-delay: 2s;
}
```