# Does a transform get applied twice if I include vendor prefix alongside regular syntax?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say I have a div

```
<div id='box'></div>
```

And in javascript/jquery I go:

```
$('#box').css('transform','translateX(300px)');
$('#box').css('-webkit-transform','translateX(300px)');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/foreyez/7fuL77h3/

Now I can run either (or both) sentences and it will run on the desktop (Chrome). But on mobile, especially iOS certain versions requires you to have -webkit prefix. So only the second one would work.

Therefore I usually include both statements in my code. And it seems to work. But I'm wondering if this is "bad". Because maybe it'll try to run both transforms, especially if it's on the desktop. Not that I notice, as it seems to work ok as you can see on the fiddle. But maybe behind the scenes it's bad mojo or something.

And if so **would it be better practice** to determine beforehand if I should use "transform" or "-webkit-transform" and just run one statement -- and if that's the case, how would I determine that? Note I'm talking javascript code here (not css). Or would it be better to just run both like I'm doing?

Answer (score 1):

You could of course do like this

```
$('#box').css({
   'transform' : 'translateX(300px)',
   '-webkit-transform' : 'translateX(300px)'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/css/),

> As of jQuery 1.8, the .css() setter will automatically take care of prefixing the property name. For example, take .css( "user-select", "none" ) in Chrome/Safari will set it as -webkit-user-select, Firefox will use -moz-user-select, and IE10 will use -ms-user-select.

So make sure you are using 1.8+ and let jQuery look after the property for you.

To answer the actual question, you should easily see if a translation of 300px is applied twice. It would be equivalent to a single translation of 600px

Answer (score 0):

It's fine. Web browsers consider prefixed and non-prefixed styles the same. For example, in Chrome `transform` will have a higher priority than `-webkit-transform` and `webkit-transform` will be ignored outright. Yet a browser that didn't know what `transform` was would ignore it and use `-webkit-transform`. (I swear it's always Safari...)

It's a bit like if you had `color: red;` immediately followed by `color: blue;`. Text would be blue and the red doesn't matter.

Comment: yes but that's in css, I understand the css is fine. But if it's in code. Doesn't it run the first statement first and then when it gets to the second statement wouldn't it try to run it again?

Comment: It might start to run the animation but since there's no difference to the browser (replacing transform with transform) it just continues the animation.

Comment: Also often back-to-back CSS modifications happen fast enough that they beat the next rendering frame and would be applied at the same time anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You're fine having both statements because the browser will only do the transform of an element once.  So if the browser takes the first transform it won't even try to do the -webkit version.  That's why if you have to do skew and translate it you have to chain the transform.

You can see more examples here: [Multiple CSS keyframe animations using transform property not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14384494/multiple-css-keyframe-animations-using-transform-property-not-working)