# Adding Two Animation to one Object [To an image]

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations

I want two animations to be given to an image one is bounce on page load and the second one is it should start swinging  once it is bounced.
I have achieved this for two different images but, when I am clubbing these two into one only one animation is working. The other animation effect is getting overwritten.

I have created a JSfiddle for [swinging](https://jsfiddle.net/tata93/8m23LLLf/) and [bounce](https://jsfiddle.net/tata93/8awkvkow/).

```css
ul { list-style-type:none;}
@-webkit-keyframes swinging {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg);
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg)
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg);
    }
}
@keyframes swinging {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg);
                transform: rotate(10deg);
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg);
                transform: rotate(-5deg)
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg);
                transform: rotate(10deg);
    }
}
.swingimage {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
    transform-origin: 50% 0;
    -webkit-animation: swinging 3.5s ease-in-out forwards infinite;
    animation: swinging 3.5s ease-in-out forwards infinite;
}
```

```html
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
  <li class="">
   <a href="#"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f5/Loxoceles_reclusa_iconized_thread.png" class="swingimage"          width="200"  height="200" > </a>
  </li>
 </ul>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14384494/multiple-css-keyframe-animations-using-transform-property-not-working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you CAN NOT add 2 different animations to the same object.so..

use the first animation ( `dropHeader` ) on the `li` and the second ( `swinging` ) on the `img`

see jsfiddle > [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mihai_T/8m23LLLf/2/)

or snippet below

add `animation-delay` on the second one ( `swinging` ) equal or bigger to the duration of the first one ( `dropHeader` ) if you want it to start after the first one has finished

in your case `animation-delay:0.5s` or bigger

```css
ul { list-style-type:none;}
@-webkit-keyframes swinging {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg);
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg)
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg);
    }
}
@keyframes swinging {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg);
                transform: rotate(10deg);
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg);
                transform: rotate(-5deg)
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg);
                transform: rotate(10deg);
    }
}
.swingimage {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
    transform-origin: 50% 0;
    -webkit-animation: swinging 3.5s ease-in-out forwards infinite;
    animation: swinging 3.5s ease-in-out forwards infinite;
    animation-delay:0.5s;
}
.bounce-effect  {

    -moz-animation-name: dropHeader;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation-duration: 0.5s;

    -webkit-animation-name: dropHeader;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;

    animation-name: dropHeader;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
}

@-moz-keyframes dropHeader {
    0% {
        -moz-transform: translateY(-40px);
    }
    100% {
        -moz-transform: translateY(0);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes dropHeader {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-40px);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    }
}
@keyframes dropHeader {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(-40px);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
}
```

```html
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
  <li class="bounce-effect ">
   <a href="#"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f5/Loxoceles_reclusa_iconized_thread.png" class="swingimage"          width="200"  height="200" > </a>
  </li>
 </ul>
```